# Best way to write a 5 star ratings system?

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

Basically I am coding a website that allows users to post sporting events. Members can then rate each event. The rating system is a 10 point system: 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0.

There are four categories:

> Organisation, Value For money, Facilities, Fun factor

I store the values in a mysql database using `float` fields.

I have used the following dummy data to test the system.

- org = 2, v4m = 4.5, fac = 4, fun = 2.5;
- org = 3.5, v4m = 4, fac = 4.5, fun = 1.5;
- org = 1, v4m = 5, fac = 4.5, fun = 2.5;

When displaying the events ratings based on the above I want each category to round to the above mentioned 5 star rating system.

So far I have the following code, which seems to work okay except for the rounding.

for example: currently the average of the three organisation ratings is `2.1666666666667` which I would like to round to `2.0`. If an average were to be `4.6666666666667` I would like it to round to `4.5`.

But how would I do this?

Heres my code so far:

```
// Count how many ratings this event has
        if($ratingCount = $event->getEventRatingCount($event_id)){

            // Get ratings for this event
            $eventRating = $event->getEventRatings($event_id);

            $organisation = 0;
            $valueForMoney = 0;
            $facilities = 0;
            $funFactor = 0;
            $overall = 0;



            foreach($eventRating AS $rating){
                $organisation   = ($organisation + $rating['organisation'] / $ratingCount);
                $valueForMoney  = ($ValueForMoney + $rating['value_for_money'] / $ratingCount);
                $facilities     = ($facilities + $rating['facilities'] / $ratingCount);
                $funFactor      = ($funFactor + $rating['fun_factor'] / $ratingCount);
            }
            echo '<br />';
            echo $organisation . '<br />';
            echo $valueForMoney . '<br />';
            echo $facilities . '<br />';
            echo $funFactor . '<br />';
            echo $overall = ($organisation + $valueForMoney + $facilities + $funFactor) / $ratingCount); 

        }else{
            // no ratings for this event
        }
```

With the dummy data I currently get these values:

```
2.1666666666667
1.6666666666667
4.3333333333333
2.1666666666667
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can multiply the rating by 2 to map it to the 1..10 range. Then round it, and divide by 2.

```
$overall = round(2*$overall)/2;
```

This will map 4.666 to 4.5  and 2.1666 to 2. A rating of 3.888 would be rounded up to 4. If you want to always round down use `floor` instead of `round`.

Comment: Depends on which 50 you use. If the ratings are 0.5, 1, 1.5, ..., 25: yes, it will.

Comment: Sorry my maths is bad ^^; So as long as the highest choice is 5 and using the methods a both (yours and mine) it should be ok?

Comment: You mean your ratings are 0.1, 0.2, ...? You are going to have to change the constants from 2 to 10 for that to work

Comment: 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0.

Comment: So there are 10 ratings, not 50?

Comment: Yeah ten choices of ratings. I wondered if it would still apply if 50 people rated, it seems to, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store each rating into a table on your database; e.g
Table

ID | Rating

1  |  4.5

2  |  3.5

3  |  3.0

Now create a query which will take all of the values from that table and create an average of all the results

You're basically just storing all your results somewhere and then working out an average

Then depending on the average create a switch or an if statement to display what you want.

Sorry, the numbers/rating didn't appear how I expected them to...

Comment: all ratings are stored in a database, sorry ill edit my question to make it clearer.